# How do I check for the existence of attributes on an object and update missing ones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, dry

So imagine I have the following code:

```
    stock = Stock.find_or_initialize_by(ticker: ticker)
    if stock.new_record?
      stock.assign_attributes(jse_link: link, name: name, price: price)
      stock.save!
      puts "#{stock.ticker} created successfully with price: #{stock.price}, name: #{stock.name} and can be viewed at #{stock.jse_link}."
    elsif stock.jse_link.empty? || stock.name.empty?
      stock.update!(jse_link: link, name: name, price: price)
      puts "#{stock.ticker} updated successfully with price: #{stock.price}, name: #{stock.name} and can be viewed at #{stock.jse_link}."
    elsif !stock.price.eql? price
      stock.update!(price: price)
      puts "#{stock.ticker} updated successfully with price: #{stock.price}."
    end
```

How do I refactor the above code to be more DRY & elegant?

Comment: Are `jse_link` and `name` always required attributes? You might want to consider a presence validation in the models then. Or do they have to match the local values? Did you consider an instance method on `Stock` to only update the record when certain conditions are met?

Comment: The question is not clear. Can you share how you would have done it and then ask for refactoring it?

Comment: @spickermann They aren't always required attributes. What's happening is I am writing a script that pings a remote HTTP endpoint and updates my local db periodically. Sometimes, due to remote calls, some data is missed. So all I want to happen is on the next go around, it basically fills in the missing data. It isn't completely mission critical if it misses it on the first time, but in subsequent times it should catch it. I didn't consider adding an instance method on `Stock` to do this. Can you show me an example of what that might look like?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I just did....refresh the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider a method in your `Stock` model like this:

```
def patch(price:, new_link:, new_name:)
  update(
    price: price,
    jse_link: (jse_link.presence || new_link),
    name: (name.presence || new_name)
  )
end
```

And use it in your controller like this without a condition:

```
if stock.new_record?
  # ...
else
  stock.patch(new_link: link, new_name: name, price: price)
end
```

Comment: Interesting. Never knew I could pass in attributes like that to a method. That's the first time I am seeing that.

Comment: The one thing you missed is the equality check on the `price`, ie if both prices match then do nothing.

Comment: Update does not update records if there was no change. IMO this should be fine, or do I miss something?

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#common-validation-options):

```
class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :link_and_name, on: :validate_link_and_name

  def link_and_name
    if jse_link.empty? && name.empty?
      errors.add(:link_and_name_empty, 'need to provide link and name')
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
stock.update(price: price)
unless stock.valid?(:validate_link_and_name)
  stock.update(jse_link: link, name: name)
end
```

Comment: This is a clever solution, the only thing is that it isn't mission critical that these attributes exist in this case. What I am doing is pinging a remote HTTP endpoint every X mins, so if it misses an attribute for an object one time I would like to be able to catch it the next time around. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you point clearly, but if you change `jse_link.empty? && name.empty?` to `jse_link.empty? || name.empty?` will be solved?

Comment: No...sorry, what I should have said is that I don't need a validation on the model because it is OK for some of the objects to not have some of the attributes sometimes, because the script will be run again in X mins and it can be updated then. Hope that clarifies what I meant.